# displaying json dict of a list of dictionaries in a csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

```
df =pd.DataFrame(eval(res))
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

This is my code to convert the data i need to a csv file but because the data is a dictionary, of a list of rougly 70 other dictionaries i can't get the format the way i want.
[image]
here i want timestamp to be my first column and then each key after that to be another column with the prices/volume at each unix timestep. How can i modify my code to achieve this? I dont need the data column.

Comment: Here all 70 rows have JSON objects or Python dictionaries?

Comment: sorry i couldnt figure out how to edit it's not JSON i get a response from an api with the data and its a string, i converted the string to this dict with eval() and thats what is being used for the csv

Comment: The dtype of the dataframe column is string right? If it's string then it's JSON. Can you please confirm whether the data in dataframe is a dictionary or row. Or can you share the csv file itself?

Comment: I am creating the csf file by using eval on the response i get from a get request, the datatype of the response i get is a string of the a dict with the data key with the value of a list of dictionaries. I used eval so it doesn't get interpreted as a string but a python dict

Comment: Okay so the data has dictionary and not JSOB. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the csv file from the image. That'll be way easier to work with.

Comment: https://www.filemail.com/d/qbxptdeojlivgkm

Comment: If you load the dataset into pandas, the `data` column is a string.

Comment: it already is a pandas dataframe, i am trying to arrange the columns and rows differently and i dont need the data title to be there

Comment: Check the update answer, it does the job with the data you sent me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed that all 70 rows in the image are JSON.

This code does the job

```
df = pd.read_csv(<csv file path>)
new_data = []

for index in df.index:
  row = eval(df.iloc[index, :].values[0])
  new_data.append(row.values())

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = row.keys())
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df["itemId"]], axis = 1)
```

Here I convert convert the JSON object in each row to a Python dictionary and then append it into a list. Once I have the whole list, I convert it into a pandas dataframe.

---

A shorter way to do this,

```
rows = list(map(eval, df["data"].values.ravel()))
vals = map(dict.values, rows)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns = list(rows)[0].keys())
new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df["itemId"]], axis = 1)
```

---

The table I get -

|  | timestamp | avgHighPrice | avgLowPrice | highPriceVolume | lowPriceVolume | itemId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1644192000 | 74099578 | 73256019 | 285 | 347 | 13652 |
| 1 | 1644213600 | 74247533 | 73363183 | 145 | 209 | 13652 |
| 2 | 1644235200 | 74056407 | 73285468 | 190 | 230 | 13652 |
| 3 | 1644256800 | 73767754 | 73119554 | 354 | 275 | 13652 |
| 4 | 1644278400 | 73463445 | 72694429 | 374 | 299 | 13652 |

Comment: apologies, if you read the other comment i explained it better. Although, i could turn the string into json and use this code?